# "Cleaning up" basic Pig Latin translator in Python

Tags: python, refactoring

As I am just a beginner, I made a small single-word Pig Latin translator in Python 3.5. I have my rough code that works, however I'd really like your opinions on how to make it more compact, pythonic, and "elegant" (i.e.-professional). Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
#Converts a word into pig latin, needs to be cleaned up
def pig_latin(word):
    word = list(word)
    first_letter = word[0]
    del word[0]
    word.insert(len(word),first_letter)
    word.insert(len(word),'ay')
    print(''.join(word))
```

Comment: Well for starters `x.insert(len(x),y)` is equivalent to `x.append(y)`.

Comment: Add documentaion strings, to describe the input and expected output.

Comment: Since you have working code, this may be more appropriate for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for that, totally forgot haha.

Comment: @PikeD. excellent idea, always good to document more!

Comment: Thanks @MosesKoledoye for the redirection, I wasn't aware that existed; I'll move it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to convert the string to a list, do some magic with it and convert it back: if you apply `[1:]` on a string, you get the string without the first character. So you can easily translate it into:

```
def pig_latin(word):
    print('%s%say'%(word[1:],word[0]))
```

or equivalently:

```
def pig_latin(word):
    print('{}{}ay'.format(word[1:],word[0]))
```

Here we use string formatting: so we replace `'%s%say'` in such way that the first `%s` is replaced with `word[1:]`, and the second with `word[0]` followed by an `'ay'`.

This generates:

```
>>> pig_latin('foobar')
oobarfay
```

Comment: I would use '.format' to make it more clear what you are doing.